# Django with jquery mobile

Tags: django, jquery-mobile, django-templates

Django provides many features for the template (`extends`, `block content` etc.) I am just learning jquery mobile, but so far when using jquery mobile, there's just one actual html page and inside it we have to create a page (`data-role="page"`). So, how can we utilize the django's templating features with jquery mobile? Or how to django with jquery mobile? Please help me understand this concept. Thank you.

Comment: Django shouldn't know about frontend frameworks. Django pass to template information by many ways and get requests. You may to make requests by jquerymobile via ajax in json format and get similar format answers from Django.

Comment: @AleksanderGordienko So, that means I can't make use of django templates with jquery mobile?